# Looking to add sub users to laravel app

Tags: laravel, authentication

Not sure if I am using the right term here but I am looking to add sub-users to my Laravel app. By this I mean once a user registers, they can create a user and assign them to a project that they have created. I have tried to do some searching but I feel I am searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: And what's holding you back from doing that?

Comment: I have gotten the authentication working and even the ability to post projects. So as it stands now users can register and create projects but each user has their own projects. I am trying to figure out how to enable those users to add / manage sub-users that will have access to the project the 'parent' user declares.

Comment: That pretty simple, a many to many relationship between users and projects. Users can have many projects and projects can have many users. Sub-users can be users, but with a simple flag on them